# Custom field not getting published in subscription apollo server

Tags: graph, react-apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to publish the newly added post, but the fields `author` and `voteCount` which are custom fields and reference another type were not being publish so that I got undefined on those fields.

My schema:

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    content: String
    voteCount: Int!
    author: User!
    votes: [Vote!]!
    createdAt: Date!
    updatedAt: Date!
  }
type Subscription {
    Post(filter: PostSubscriptionFilter): PostSubscriptionPayload
  }
  input PostSubscriptionFilter {
    mutation_in: [_ModelMutationType!]
  }
  type PostSubscriptionPayload {
    mutation: _ModelMutationType!
    node: Post
  }
  enum _ModelMutationType {
    CREATED
    UPDATED
    DELETED
  }
```

Resolver

```
Mutation: {
    addPost: async (
      root,
      { title, content },
      { ValidationError, models: { Post }, user },
    ) => {
      if (!user) {
        throw new ValidationError('unauthorized');
      }
      const post = new Post({
        title,
        content,
        author: user.id,
      });
      await post.save();
      pubsub.publish('Post', { Post: { mutation: 'CREATED', node: post } });
      return post;
    },
},
Subscription: {
    Post: {
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('Post'),
    },
  },
Post: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
    id: root => root.id || root._id,
    author: async ({ author }, data, { dataLoaders: { userLoader } }) => {
      const postAuthor = await userLoader.load(author);
      return postAuthor;
    },
    voteCount: async ({ _id }, data, { models: { Vote } }) => {
      const voteCount = await Vote.find({ post: _id }).count();
      return voteCount || 0;
    },
    votes: async ({ _id }, data, { models: { Vote } }) => {
      const postVotes = await Vote.find({ post: _id });
      return postVotes || [];
    },
  },
```

And the subscription in React client:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.subscribeToNewPosts();
  }
subscribeToNewPosts() {
    this.props.allPostsQuery.subscribeToMore({
      document: gql`
        subscription {
          Post(filter: { mutation_in: [CREATED] }) {
            node {
              id
              title
              content
              updatedAt
              voteCount
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      updateQuery: (previous, { subscriptionData }) => {
        // const result = Object.assign({}, previous, {
        //   allPosts: [subscriptionData.data.Post.node, ...previous.allPosts],
        // });
        // return result;
        console.log(subscriptionData);
        return previous;
      },
    });
  }
```

The field `voteCount` is undefined:
[image]

While using queries or mutations, it get published normally, what should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing doesn't necessarily mean that `voteCount` is null -- rather it means you're trying to destructure an undefined value instead of an object. The path tells you this error occurred while attempting to resolve `voteCount`. You utilize destructuring within your resolve function in two places -- once with the root object and again with context. There should be a root object with you to work with, so I imagine the issue is with context.

When you set up context for a typical GraphQL server, you do so by utilizing middleware (like `graphqlExpress`) to essentially inject it into the request you're making. When you use subscriptions, everything is done over websockets, so the middleware is never hit and your context is therefore null.

To get around this, I think you'll need to inject the same context into your subscriptions -- you can see [an example of how to do that here](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-subscriptions/authentication.html).

Comment: OMG! You saved my day! Thank you so much!